# WCF transport security configuration question

Tags: c#, wcf, security, iis, wcf-security

We have Windows Service with tcp binding. It has a transport security mode and client credential type is Windows. Service is within a domain.

Now we want to make calls to this service from the ASP.NET application running on IIS which is not part of the domain. We don't need user impersonation. What is the most secure way to enable this sort of communication?

This is a pretty standard situation: Web server is in DMZ and I would like to know how to set a secure communication with WCF backend services.

Comment: You could also consider using federated security, but that's a whole new world of pain you'd be signing yourself up for. If you would use federated security outside this single application, then it might be worth it, but otherwise I'd go with 2 different endpoints like Ladislav recommended below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that it will not work. You cannot use `Windows` client credential type if you want to consume the service outside of your domain. You must use `Certificate` (or `None` but it means no authentication).

The difference is that `Windows` client credentials will create stream secured with SSPI whereas `Certificate` and `None` client credentials will create stream secured with SSL certificate. In case of `Certificate` client credentials each client will be identified by its own certificate (= you need one for your IIS server).

Comment: Ladislav, do you know if service could combine these two methods? say if caller IP is IIS then apply certificate authentication, otherwise windows.

Comment: I believe it should simply work with exposing two different endpoints - each with its own net.tcp configuration.